# Using URIs in $ref with ajv-cli

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I would like to validate a JSON file against a JSON schema, which uses `$ref` to reference an external schema via a URI:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "$id": "https://reconciliation-api.github.io/specs/latest/schemas/manifest.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "authentication": {
         "$ref": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json#/definitions/basicAuthenticationSecurity"
      }
   }
}
```

I would expect the validator to fetch the linked schema on the fly and use it to validate my JSON. I have tried using `ajv-cli` for this:

```
ajv test -s my_schema.json -r "\\\*" -d my_file.json
```

I would expect that the `-r "\\\*"` allows reference to any schema, but instead I get the following error:

```
error: can't resolve reference https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json#/definitions/basicAuthenticationSecurity
from id https://reconciliation-api.github.io/specs/latest/schemas/manifest.json#
```

Does `ajv-cli` support fetching remote schemas on the fly? If not, is there any other validator which does support that?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at https://ajv.js.org/#ref suggests you need to enable async reference resolution: https://ajv.js.org/#asynchronous-schema-compilation

You need to define a `loadSchema` function as an option in the ajv instantiation, then call `compileAsync`.

The example from the docs is as follows:

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({ loadSchema: loadSchema });

ajv.compileAsync(schema).then(function (validate) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  // ...
});

function loadSchema(uri) {
  return request.json(uri).then(function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode >= 400)
      throw new Error('Loading error: ' + res.statusCode);
    return res.body;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's possible to do that in ajv itself - but I am wondering if the CLI supports that?

Comment: I doubt it as you have to provide a function.

Comment: Note that if you want to do this on the frontend with a `request` module, you can use `fetch`, e.g.: `async function loadSchema(uri) {
const res = await fetch(uri);
if (res.status >= 400) {
throw new Error('Loading error: ' + res.status);
}
return await res.json();
}`